# Add result to Search Field for Auto Suggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, autocomplete

I have made a made this to fetch categories from a text file which works fine and below is the HTML search form that does the traditional searching stuff (working fine again). I have to show the result (which is an Array) as auto suggest similar to popular search engines and I know how to iterate the loop of result but I cannot think as to how should I show this as autosuggest. I did not use the jquery-ui auto suggest which is popularly used because I want my efforts on this.

Can anyone hint me how to show this result as auto suggest?

**JS**

```
<script>
   var mcats = '';
   var result = new Array();
   $.get('http://dev-m.xxxx.com/location/mcats_24-11-2014.txt', function(data){
      //console.clear();
        console.log("Reading Local File..");
        mcats = data.split("\n");
      //console.log(mcats);

        $("#mainSearch").keyup(function(event){
           if($("#mainSearch").val().length>=3){
              console.clear();
              $("#input").html('');
              $("#input").html($("#mainSearch").val() + "  " + $("#mainSearch").val().length);
              var tobe = $("#mainSearch").val();

              for(var i=0;i<mcats.length;i++){ 
                   if(mcats[i].indexOf(tobe)>-1){
                        //  console.log(arr[i].indexOf(tobe));
                        result.push([ mcats[i], mcats[i].indexOf(tobe)]);
               }
           }
           result = result.sort(function(a,b) {
           return a[1] > b[1];
        });
        console.log(result);
      }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id='search' action='' method='POST'>
<label for="mainSearch"><b>Enter Keyword: </b></label>
<input type='text' name='mainSearch' id='mainSearch' />
<input type='Submit' value='Search' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html5-feature datalist: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

To link it with your own autocomplete-data, create the datalist-element in the ajax-callback (when you have the data).

http://jsfiddle.net/hkLj9mxo/1/

Comment: hi @Johannes I know about the datalist tag but I want better options then this. datalist does not support custom css moreover this creates a dropdown list which has to be opened by the user instead i want this to open and resize automatically all the options!